# Получить только Id пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Есть код который достает из бд пользователя по его никнейму:

```
var currentUser = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

все прекрасно работает, НО я не могу додумать как мне получить только Id пользователя, ведь дальше в методе я использую только его, вся остальная информация не нужна, но в распоряжении есть только `User.Identity.Name` т.е. имя пользователя

Comment: Просто возьмите `currentUser?.Id`

Comment: @АндрейNOP нужно из бд загрузить только Id, все остальное принципиально должно остаться там, вопрос решил, ответ ниже оформил. Просто если у юзера 100 полей, а нам нужно 1, зачем дополнительно грузить еще 99.

Answer (score 0):

Решается вот так:

```
var currentUserId = await db.Users
                .Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                .Select(x=> x.Id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```